# When is the AS keyword optional vs required?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, alias

Is there a "rule set" for when the AS keyword is optional vs required, or is it solely contextual, based on the language specifications for the statements it is used in?

For example, when being used for alias it is optional.
It's also optional when being used to declare variables (and I believe to use `cast` too).
But it is not optional when creating UDFs and procedures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are in essence asking for the language design decision on when (and why) the AS keyword is optional or required. While this is impossible to answer definitively without referencing the minutes of the design committee meetings, it is likely required **exactly where needed to make an unambiguous grammar**, and optional elsewhere to maintain the **natural language quality** originally espoused by the language creator.

Comment: @iliketocode: There may be comments in the language standard spec; but that is typically very dry reading.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have any formal rules for you, but from a practical perspective, for column aliases, I always use AS, as IMO it sometimes makes the intent of the code easier to follow.

e.g. :

```
create table dbo.Table1  (id int primary key, col1 varchar(100), col2 varchar(100), Name varchar(100))

insert dbo.Table1 (id, col1, col2, name) values (1, 'this is col1', 'this is col2', 'this is name')
GO

select col1, col2 Name from dbo.Table1 -- X
select col1, col2 as Name from dbo.Table1  -- Y
```

Now, both lines X and Y give you the same result. In line X, it may not be clear if the coder made a typo and left out a comma between col2 and Name. In line Y, it seems the coder explicitly wants to return col2 as column name "Name".

This may not be the best example, but I've seen problems similar to the above caused by leaving out the "as", where typos were harder to see.

Comment: By contrast, I **never** use AS unless the compiler requires it. Each to his own I guess, but I use a lot more white space and line-feeds to format my SQL.

Comment: it's interesting that different things work for different people.

Answer (score 0):

Intuitively, it seems like the `AS` keyword is option when it's being used to create an alias, but otherwise is required. I believe it is also required as part of a `CAST` statement.

Also, this existing question may be more relevant than the one that you found:

[How to know where AS keyword should be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1633576/how-to-know-where-as-keyword-should-be-used)