# PostgreSQL: Meaning of 'AS f(x)' Clause in SELECT Statement

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

In a presentation on Window functions made by EDB (https://youtu.be/XO1WnmJs9RI), they start out with what they call the simplest form of a window function as this:

```
SELECT *
FROM generate_series(1, 10) AS f(x);
```

What is the meaning of the `AS f(x)` clause at the end of this statement? I searched the documentation under both the SELECT command and the window function, and cannot find any explanation for this syntax. I know that the `AS` portion allows us to rename the column, but I am clueless on the `f(x)` part.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to know where AS keyword should be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1633576/how-to-know-where-as-keyword-should-be-used)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is simply a [table alias](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-TABLE-ALIASES) that defines the result of `generate_series()`:

- The table reference is `f`.
- The column reference is `x`.

The `as` is optional (and I leave it out of table aliases).

So, you could write the `select` as:

```
select f.x
```

This is handy when you want to use the value for other purposes, such as calculations and `join`s.

Comment: Great! So, I've figured out the meaning of `SELECT * FROM unnest('{blind,mouse}'::text[], '{1,2,3}'::text[]) AS f(t,i);` and `SELECT f.t FROM (VALUES ('{Alex,Sonia}'::text[]), ('{46,43}'::text[])) AS f(t);`.